# LATCH and PORT, dsPIC33f

Tags: port, mplab

I am referring to a simple program (example 2)  on http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2123&param=en024284

```
#include "p33Fxxxx.h"

#pragma config WDT = OFF

void main (void)
{
  TRISB = 0;

  /* Reset the LEDs */
  PORTB = 0;

  /* Light the LEDs */
  LATB = 0x005A;// tested with PORTB= 0X005A;at first, no change of PORTB in watch                      
                   window
  while (1)
  ;
}
```

In the watch window, latchB is changed to 0x5A successfully while PORTB remains 0x0000.
I wonder why it is so.
If I were to connect portb to LEDs would they light up?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I forgot to set analog input to digital by AD1PCFGL=0xffff;